# Looking for dropdown multiselect filter for woocommerce product in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I need woo-commerce filter to look like this http://fschumacher.com/catalog/Fabrics. how can i achieve this drop-down multi-select category filter?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this plugin [Advanced AJAX Product Filters](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-ajax-filters/)
 Or you can go with custom solution
, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To have a Custom Product Filter like that, it's better to choose a plugin that does that.

The below are the 2 free WordPress plugins which does the job.

[Woocommerce Product Filters](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-products-filter/)

[Woocommerce Ajax Filters](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-ajax-filters/)

Do let me know if it works for you.